# What does "prospect" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

In this sentence from a UN document:

> The prospect of direct and personal access to the discovery and enjoyment of the planet’s resources constitutes a right equally open to all the world’s inhabitants
>   ([Source](http://ethics.unwto.org/en/content/global-code-ethics-tourism-article-7))

I wonder what prospect means here. Neither *possibility* nor *view* fits well here, supposedly.

Comment: **prospect** : a particular event which will probably or definitely happen in the future...from Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English

Comment: thx, Could you paraphrase this *The prospect of direct and personal access to the discovery and enjoyment of the planet’s resources *? Does it say that this will happen in the future? then why is is said *constitutes a right equally open to all the world’s inhabitants*?

Comment: The event (situation) where such thing will probably or definitely happen constitute a right which is equally open to all inhabitants. **Such thing**, of course, refers to direct and personal access to the discovery and enjoyment of the planet's resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with [***prospect***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/prospect) sense 5a:

> 5a) something hoped for or expected; anticipated outcome

So:

> The **hope/expectation** of direct and personal access to the discovery and enjoyment of the planet’s resources constitutes a right equally open to all the world’s inhabitants.

So it is saying the world's inhabitants have the *hope or expectation* of discovering and enjoying the planet’s resources.

As such, we have no idea or guarantee if this is what will actually happen.

Comment: You mean because they want it, this constitutes a right for them? May be people want many other things, so it constitutes a right? if you are a native, would you tell me if you find this sentence proper English? Looks like the writers of the code are not native English speakers and produce poor English quite a lot!

Comment: Not because they "want it". Most people would agree if someone digs in their backyard and finds a gold nugget then they should be able to keep it. A more controversial topic (and I'm guessing more in line with the author's statement) would be about a "right" to collect rainwater.  See [is collecting rainwater illegal](https://www.google.com/search?q=is+collecting+rainwater+illegal).  This author would likely say it should not be illegal.  Why?  Because of "the prospect (hope/expectation) of direct and personal access".